# Can I use TextMate with existing Flex projects created in Flex / Flash Builder?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, ide, textmate

I am wondring if anyone has a good resource for opening existing Flex projects that where created in Flex / Flash Builder and run them using the TextMate bundle for Flex and Actionscript projects.

Basically I just want to know if I can walk into an existing project and configure this easily or am I pretty much stuck with using Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doable, but it's pretty hard, cumbersome and not pretty. Don't get me wrong, I love TextMate, but for all the pros of eclipse (auto completion, profiling, etc...) and the main con of it being eclipse; I've never moved.

This is a good place to start though, there are some good AS3 and Flex bundles out there:

http://pixelate.de/blog/setting-up-a-as3-project-in-textmate

But like I said, you don't get auto completion, code lookup, etc...

Comment: Yeah so the answer is as simple as this .... If you have an existing flex project that you would like to use with the textmate flex bundle all you really need to do is open the project in textmate and then you need to create a build.xml file so that the textmate bundle and hand that off the the command line compiler that it uses so that  all your project dependencies are used during compilation. 

A tip for creating build.xml automatically is, I would suggestion that you install a plugin from elementriver.com called sourcemate. There plugin will export a build.xml file from FlashBuilder for u.